# CassandraIO + Apache Beam

Tags: apache-beam, apache-beam-io, beam

I have been attempting to find information on how to utilize Apache Beam with Cassandra in Python, but I have not been successful in my search. I am curious if the use of cassandraio library is supported for Python? If anyone could provide any insight or resources on this matter, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 0):

The `CassandraIO` exists natively in `Beam` `Java` but unfortunately not in `Beam` `Python`.

You can check this [link](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/connectors/) to have the list of supported IOs with `Beam`.

The [Javadoc](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/current/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/cassandra/CassandraIO.html) for `CassandraIO`.

I also saw this [link](https://github.com/srfrnk/beam-playground/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/ReadCassandra.java) with an example from a `Github` repository.